# Paging in Rediis

Tags: redis

I am running local rediis for my application. I am using ServiceStack.Rediis client with C#.
I am storing items as an object type T with some key.
For example

```
Key "1234" : {
object {
 name : "abcd",
 value : "1"
}
}
```

I am storing something like 10000 objects of same type with key. I would like to apply pagination when i retrieve these objects and only show like 20 per page.
Is this possible? If yes, what should be a good way to resolve this?

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command with a count of 20.